# React and SVG with namespaces Extensions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, jsx

I have a project that requires react and SVG. I need to insert SVG into anoder, dinamically, in a specific location.

The file given from the customer has made by visio and contains some specific namespaces, first of all this:

```
xmlns:v="http://schemas.microsoft.com/visio/2003/SVGExtensions/"
```

This means tags like this, somewhere in the code:

```
<linearGradient
    v:background="#4d4d4d"
    v:foreground="#ffffff"
    v:fillPattern="26"
    ... >
```

How is it possible to use this attributes or tags in react?

Thanks, Davide.

Answer (score 0):

Before putting SVG in your website, you should always try to optimize it.
[svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo) can help; you can even run it in your build.